# Concept Based Text Summarization (Abstraction)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, summarization

I am looking for an engine that does AI text summarization based on the concept or meaning of the sentence, I looked at open-source projects like (ginger, paraphrase, ace) but they don't do the job.
The way they work is that they try to find synonyms for each word and replace with the current words, this way they generate alot of alternatives to a sentence but the meaning is wrong most of the times.

I have worked with Stanford's engine to do something like highlights to an article and based on that extract the most important sentences, but still this is not abstraction, its extraction.

It would also make sense that the engine I'm looking for learns over time and results are improved after each summary.

Please help out here, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you created this system?

Comment: No, not yet ...

Comment: I also would recommend you to use word2vec & doc2vec to handle all routine like synonymous, word meaning in context & the general category of the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t know any open source project which fits your requirements about abstraction and a meaning as I assume.

But I have an ideas how to build such engine and how to train it.

In a few words I think we all keep in mind some Bayesian-network  like structure in our minds, with helps us not only to classify some data, but also to form an abstract meaning about text or message.

Since it is impossible to extract all that abstract categories structure from our mind I think it’s better to build mechanism which allow as to reconstruct it step-by-step.

**Abstract**

The key idea of the proposed solution is in the extraction of meaning of a conversation using approaches which easier in operation with it from an automated computer system. This will allow creating the good level of illusion of real conversation with another person.

Proposed model supports two levels of abstraction:

**First of them**, less complex level consists in the recognition of groups of words or a single word as a group which related to the category, instance or to the instance attribute.

Instance means instantiation from the general category of the real or abstract subject, object, action, attribute or other kind of instances. As an example – concrete relation between two or more subjects: concrete relations between employer and employee, concrete city and country where it’s situated and so on.
This basic meaning recognition approach allows us to create bot with ability sustain a conversation. This ability based on recognition of basic elements of meaning: categories, instances and instances attributes.

**Second**, the most complicated method based on scenario recognition and storing them into the conversation context with instances/categories as well as using them for completion some of recognized scenarios.

Related scenarios will be used to complete the next message of the conversation as well as some of scenarios can be used to generate the next message or for recognizing meaning element by using of conditions and by using meaning elements from the context.

Something like that:

[image]

Basic classification should be entered manually and with future correction/addition of the teachers.

Words from sentence in conversation and scenarios from sentence can be filled from context

Conversation scenarios/categories can be fulfilled by previously recognized instances or with instances described in future conversation (self-learning)

Pic 1 – word detection/categorization basically flow vision

Pic 2 – general system vision big picture view

Pic 3 - meaning element classification

Pic 4 – basically categories structure could be like that